# concerning "at daytime"

Tags: phrase-usage

> A: As often on Internet forums, at the question "why stars are not
>   visible at daytime" posted by an amateur it is not enough to answer
>   "because the sun shines, ---“ (from google)

Would it be really OK to use "at daytime" as meaning "during the day"?

Answer (score 5):

"in the daytime" or "during the daytime" would be a much more natural and usual construction. I suspect this was devised by analogy with "at night" which is of course very normal.

However, in context it is perfectly clear what is meant, even if it sounds a bit odd. I don't know why we use "at night" but not "at day" in English, but normally we don't.

Comment: People also use "at nighttime" which would be the counterpart to "at daytime".