# Are "night" and "nighttime" the same and "day" and "daytime" the same?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

According to my study, "**in the night**" or "**during the night**" is **NOT** the same as "**at nighttime**". **In the night**" or "**during the night** say that something happens **at some time during a particular night** while "**at nighttime**" says that something **often happens** during the night.

These are the same

> The baby kept crying in the night.
>
> The baby kept crying during the night.
>
> The baby kept crying at nighttime. (not correct and we don't have "**at the nighttime**")

---

"**At night**" and "**at nighttime**" are the same because they both say that something **often happens** during the night

These 2 sentences are the same

> Animals hunt at nighttime
>
> Animals hunt at night

---

"**In the day**" and "**during the day**" are the same as "**in/during the daytime**". They all  say that something **happens regularly** during the time between dawn and sunset:

These are the same

> -I can’t sleep in the daytime.
>
> -I can’t sleep during the daytime.
>
> -I can’t sleep in the day.
>
> -I can’t sleep during the day.

I m not sure what to say when we say that something happens **at some time during a particular night**?

It is very confusing.

Comment: Context can change the meaning. *"Deliveries will be made during the daytime,"* (regular occurrence in daylight hours) might be different than *"Deliveries will be made during the day,"* (multiple deliveries over the span of one particular day). **"What to say when something *happens* at some time during a particular night?"** The confusion might be your verb tense. "Something *will happen* during the night," and "something *happened* during the night," sound more like 1-time events, whereas "something *happens* during the night" suggests a nightly event.

Comment: Please see [“In the day” vs. “in the daytime”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/253572/in-the-day-vs-in-the-daytime) and [concerning “at daytime”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/217882/concerning-at-daytime)

Comment: There's the famous Sherlock Holmes quotation [the curious incident of the dog in the night-time](http://www.bestofsherlock.com/top-10-sherlock-quotes.htm#incident) which refers to a non-event on a particular night. Your generalisations are not necessarily correct, I'm afraid.